# Django Nested Serialization

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

this is my serializor.py

```py
class AddressSerializor(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = AddressSerializor(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Persion
        fields = ('id' ,'name', 'age', 'a' )
```

this is my models page :

```py
class Persion(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=200)
   
    

class Address(models.Model):
    city = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    state = models.TextField(max_length=301)
    cuntry =  models.TextField(max_length=222)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `a` on serializer `PersonSerializer`.

The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Persion` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Persion' object has no attribute 'a'.
```

can any one help me what am i missing, as iam new to django i may miss the basic syntax too, Iam feguring this nearly 2 days no luck

Comment: show your Persion model

Comment: edit your question and add the model there

Comment: Done need any more information, Iam really stuck on this for 2 days

Comment: you don't have a relationship between your "Persion" model and your "Address" model, you need to have some kind of relationship if you want a person to have an address (or multiple addresses) look into Django's ForeignKey, OneToOne, and ManyToMany to see which one works for you. But generally would each person have one address or can they have multiple addresses ?

Comment: in my case one address and i should learn Django's ForeignKey, OneToOne, concept right?

Answer (score 0):

Since according to your comments you have one address per person, you can technically put the address fields in the Person model, but if you want to separate it you need to link them like

```py
class Address(models.Model):
    city = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    state = models.TextField(max_length=301)
    cuntry =  models.TextField(max_length=222)


class Persion(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, 
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    null=True, # allow field to be null
                                    blank=True) # allow field to be blank (for admin interface)
```

This way the Persion would have an `address` field that would be of type Address model.

and your serializers

```
class AddressSerializor(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializor() #note that address is the same name in the Persion model
    class Meta:
        model = Persion
        fields = ('id' ,'name', 'address' )
```

in your question you had `age` as a field but you don't have an age field in the Persion model, you will need to add that.

check out the fields in Django docs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields

Comment: File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Api\restFrameWork\serializer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from restFrameWork.models import Address, Persion
ImportError: cannot import name 'Address' from partially initialized module 'restFrameWork.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Api\restFrameWork\models.py)

Comment: @nikhildeepak did you run make migrations and migrate?

Comment: getting thiss error while migrating @jimmar

Comment: it's saying you are not importing things correctly in your serializer.py file, I suggest you open another question and include your whole serializer.py file not just snippets

Comment: yep that has been solved but i dont need foriegn key value allone!. i need full full table. can u help

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a foreign key relationship between a `Person` and an `Address`. You can add the foreign key declaration to your models, and then generate/run migrations using `python manage.py makemigrations <name-of-app>` and `python manage.py migrate`.

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    ...  # the other model fields
    address = models.ForeignKey(
        "Address",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Comment: from restFrameWork.models import Address, Persion
ImportError: cannot import name 'Address' from partially initialized module 'restFrameWork.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Api\restFrameWork\models.py)

Comment: getting above metioned error while migrating